# how to access http.Server.connection property in express 3 router?

Tags: node.js, express, connect

I would like to use http.Server.connections in my express 3 route?
Is there no way to get it anymore?

Should I just 
   app.set('server', server);

express.createServer() is deprecated and express applications no longer inherit from http.Server

```
var app = express(),
server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(8080);
...
module.exports = function (app) {

    app.get('/connections', function (req, res) {
        res.send({
            connections: app.connections 
            // app != http.Server in express 3
        });
    });

};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `app.connections` you need to send `server.connections`, since you've used:

`server = http.createServer(app);`

So your code becomes:

```
app.get('/connections', function (req, res) {
    res.send({
        connections: server.connections 
    });
});
```

Comment: important to note here that app.listen() does not return a normal http server, thus you must create a server manually to access server methods

Answer (score 0):

```
app.locals.connections = app.connections
```

Then in your response:

```
res.send({ connections: res.locals.connections});
```